# Chat in angular 2

Tags: angular, messaging

I would like to do a messaging in angular 2 but I have a problem.

My problem is : how to do for the list of received messages refreshes automatically when another user sends me a message ? (now I must to refresh the page to have it). Maybe I can use Observable but how ?

Comment: You're going to want to look into using web sockets. This will allow real time updates for messages sent.

Comment: You might want to use socket-io for receiving and sending messages to the server. Just use observables subscribe when you receive any message from the server. https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat will be helpful in making that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See how to use Websockets API. 
Here you have an example http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

You can also use http streaming instead. 
An example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events